# How Can I find the coordinates of a point, if I know its projection vector?

Tags: vector-spaces

in this equation for vector projections, using the dot product

$$ {{proj_\vec{a}\vec{b}} } = { \frac {\vec a \cdot \vec b}{\lVert\vec a \rVert^2} }  \vec a $$

if I know everything BUT vector $\vec b$ , is it possible to solve for it and find it? I am not sure if I can split the $\vec a \cdot \vec b$ dot product.

The idea here is that I have 4 points $ABCD$ in 3D space. I need to find a point P along line AB, if I know the projection of P on line CD.

thank you.

Comment: Your first expression is flawed. The left side is a scalar while the right side is a vector.

Comment: @Dr.MV you are right. fixed now. taken from http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/DotProduct.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is not possible, unless you've got more information. Many vectors can have the same projection along a fixed vector; a simple picture should convince you.

In your particular case with the $4$ points in space, you do have some extra constraints. In essence, knowing the projection of a vector $u$ along a fixed direction $v$ specifies $u$ up to a line (in the sense of an affine subspace); again, the picture for this is pretty clear. You are looking for the intersection of this line with the segment $AB$, and there is only one such intersection so long as the points are in general position.

Comment: Hi there! could you elaborate some more? I'm not sure what you mean with `fixed direction v`. also if I understand correct, your vector $u$ is my vector $AP$. right? but $AP$ is a segment of $AB$, so the 2 coincide - there is not just one intersection point. right?

Comment: $v$ is the vector you project against, it's the $a$ in your notation. But the magnitude of $v$ doesn't change the projection; only the direction $v$ is pointing in matters, so sometimes we refer to a projection in a given direction, often specified by a unit vector.

Comment: hmm and "specifies $u$ up to a line` means? Which is this line? I still cannot see how the intersection (of what) will give me a result.. (sorry 3am here)

Comment: It means that if you know the projection of $u$ in the direction of $v$, then there is a line that you know $u$ must lie in; at least when you're in $2$ dimensions. In $3$ dimensions this is a plane. If you draw what a projection means geometrically in $2$ dimensions, then you should be able to find this line pretty easily, and in $3$ dimensions you just need to revolve this line to generate the plane. (By this I mean, *go draw the picture or you won't see what I'm saying.*)

Comment: I can only definitely see what you are saying if *you* draw the picture :) . Having said that I have drawn the picture and it looks like this for 2d http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/DotProduct.aspx (scroll down to **projections**), is this the line you refer to? (ie $b$ projected onto $a$ ?

Comment: or rather see this. http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~glarose/classes/calcIII/web/13_5/ there is a plane too. The thing is in 3D space a multitude of vectors  (all lying on the plane) will intersect with "the line" $u$ to which  you refer. no?

Comment: Yes, that dotted line is the line I'm referring to. You can probably see that if you extend the dotted line and let $c$ be any vector along this line, then $c$ and $b$ have the same projections onto $a$. Now, if these points were to lie in $3$-dimensional space, then you can also revolve this dotted line to generate a plane, all of whose vectors will have the same projection onto $a$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21584/discussion-between-nass-and-neuguy).